# What's the best way of nesting a loop with the same number of iterations?

Tags: python, loops

```
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(N):
      print(i,j)
```

This is the code I wrote and it does what I want it to. However, it seems repetitive to write N twice and explicitly write the loop twice as there are 3 lines and they are not information dense at all. I feel like I should not be explicitly writing the number of iterations twice when they are the same, they are both equal to N. Is there a better way to do this in Python?

Comment: There's some mild duplication, but this is likely the cleanest ready-to-go solution afaik. You might be able to create your own helper, but I can't see it being worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

for i, j in product(range(N), repeat=2):
    print(i, j)
```

Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Thumbs up for itertools.  This way of creating generators is easy, efficient, and lends it'self to functional programming patterns like `map`,`filter`, and `reduce`

Comment: It's such a gem of a module. It's very rare that I'm working on a project where I don't end up importing it somewhere.